# Why the variable FileStream writer is null?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

There are two cases where i'm using the writer.

```
private void downloadFile(Int32 fileNr)
        {
            FileStream writer = null;
            m_currentFileSize = 0;
            fireEventFromBgw(Event.FileDownloadAttempting);

            FileInfo file = this.Files[fileNr];
            FileInfo fileFirstDateTime = this.Files[0];
            FileInfo fileLastDateTime = this.Files[19];
            Int64 size = 0;

            Byte[] readBytes = new Byte[this.PackageSize];
            Int32 currentPackageSize;
            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch speedTimer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            Int32 readings = 0;
            Exception exc = null;

            if (form1.checkBox1.Text == "Download satellite images")
            {
                LocalDirectorySettings(file, writer);
            }
            else
            {
                writer = new FileStream(this.LocalDirectory + "\\" + file.Name, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
            }


            HttpWebRequest webReq;
            HttpWebResponse webResp = null;

            try
            {
                webReq = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(this.Files[fileNr].Path);
                webResp = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();

                size = webResp.ContentLength;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { exc = ex; }

            m_currentFileSize = size;
            fireEventFromBgw(Event.FileDownloadStarted);

            if (exc != null)
            {
                bgwDownloader.ReportProgress((Int32)InvokeType.FileDownloadFailedRaiser, exc);
            }
            else
            {
                m_currentFileProgress = 0;
                while (m_currentFileProgress < size && !bgwDownloader.CancellationPending)
                {
                    while (this.IsPaused) { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); }

                    speedTimer.Start();

                    currentPackageSize = webResp.GetResponseStream().Read(readBytes, 0, this.PackageSize);

                    m_currentFileProgress += currentPackageSize;
                    m_totalProgress += currentPackageSize;
                    fireEventFromBgw(Event.ProgressChanged);
                    try
                    {
                        writer.Write(readBytes, 0, currentPackageSize);
                    }
                    catch(Exception eee)
                    {
                        string myeee = eee.ToString();
                    }
                    readings += 1;

                    if (readings >= this.StopWatchCyclesAmount)
                    {
                        m_currentSpeed = (Int32)(this.PackageSize * StopWatchCyclesAmount * 1000 / (speedTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds + 1));
                        speedTimer.Reset();
                        readings = 0;
                    }
                }

                speedTimer.Stop();
                writer.Close();
                webResp.Close();
                if (!bgwDownloader.CancellationPending) { fireEventFromBgw(Event.FileDownloadSucceeded); }
            }
            fireEventFromBgw(Event.FileDownloadStopped);
        }
```

When in this part if it does the else part it's working fine:

```
if (form1.checkBox1.Text == "Download satellite images")
            {
                LocalDirectorySettings(file, writer);
            }
            else
            {
                writer = new FileStream(this.LocalDirectory + "\\" + file.Name, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
            }
```

If it's doing the line: It's fine:

```
writer = new FileStream(this.LocalDirectory + "\\" + file.Name, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
```

But once i'm changing the checkbox and it does the first part of the IF:

```
LocalDirectorySettings(file, writer);
```

And this is the LocalDirectorySettings method code:

```
public void LocalDirectorySettings(FileInfo file, FileStream writer)
        {
            try
            {
                var startIndex = file.Path.IndexOf("region=") + "region=".Length;
                var length = file.Path.IndexOf("&", startIndex) - startIndex;
                var code = file.Path.Substring(startIndex, length);
                var countryName = form1.codeToFullNameMap[code];

                string firstDT = ParseDateTime(this.Files[0]);
                string lastDT = ParseDateTime(this.Files[19]);
                string subDirectoryDT = firstDT + "---" + lastDT;

                string countryPath = Path.Combine(form1.mainPath, countryName);
                LocalDirectory = countryPath + "\\" + subDirectoryDT;

                if (!Directory.Exists(LocalDirectory))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(LocalDirectory);
                }

                string fileName = this.LocalDirectory + "\\" + "test.png"; //file.Name + "---" + countFilesNames++.ToString("D6") + ".png";
                writer = new FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create); // Set a breakpoint here.
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                string ggg = err.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Even that there is a line with instance of writer inside the LocalDirectorySettings method:

```
writer = new FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
```

And i'm using a break point and it does getting to this line in the LocalDirectorySettings but then when it continue to the part:

```
try
                    {
                        writer.Write(readBytes, 0, currentPackageSize);
                    }
                    catch(Exception eee)
                    {
                        string myeee = eee.ToString();
                    }
```

It's getting to the catch part say writer is null. And using a break point i see that writer is null.

Why when it's getting to the LocalDirectorySettings the writer is null after it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the parameter, a local variable named `writer` in the `LocalDirectorySettings()` method, has no effect on the *other* local variable, also named `writer`, found in the caller, `downloadFile()`.

I would strongly advise *against* using a class field to share this object (as proposed in the other answer). There's no reason to, and doing so will just clutter your class. Instead, either pass the parameter by-reference or, much better, just have the `LocalDirectorySettings()` method return the object. E.g.:

```
void downloadFile(int fileNr)
{
    FileStream writer;

    //...

    if (form1.checkBox1.Text == "Download satellite images")
    {
        writer = LocalDirectorySettings(file);
    }
    else
    {
        writer = new FileStream(this.LocalDirectory + "\\" + file.Name, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
    }

    //...
}

public FileStream LocalDirectorySettings(FileInfo file)
{
    try
    {
        //...

        string fileName = this.LocalDirectory + "\\" + "test.png"; //file.Name + "---" + countFilesNames++.ToString("D6") + ".png";
        return new FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        string ggg = err.ToString();
        throw; // you don't actually handle the exception, so rethrowing
               // is the appropriate action here. Your only alternative
               // would be to return "null" and have the caller check for
               // that return value explicitly.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `LocalDirectorySettings` you are assigning a new `FileStream` to the function parameter. This does not effect the writer variable in `downloadFile`.

Make `writer` a member variable so the two methods can share it.

```
FileStream writer = null;
private void downloadFile(Int32 fileNr)
{
    // Do stuff with writer
}

public void LocalDirectorySettings(FileInfo file)
{
    // Do stuff with writer
}
```